# R- creating a function that creates names of variables

Tags: r, function, variables

I want to create a function who create a name depending of its argument.
I tried:

```
a <- function(x){ assign(paste("train",x,sep=""),4]) }
```

But when i do `a(3)` for example, nothing happens. what's wrong?

Thanks for your help.

edit: I will be more specific as requested.

I want to do a feature selection: the idea is to use a function to generate different subsets of features, generate a training set for each subset, then use the output of this function in another function (let's say lm() ) to test each training set. the number of subsets/training set is variable and I don't know how to store them in order to re-use them later.

Comment: The assignment was not done in the global environment. (Don't use `assign` if you don't know what that means.) This question needs a use case so a more correct method can be suggested. It's really a bad idea to create a bunch of "loose" variables. You will have a hell of a time managing them programmatically.

Answer (score -1):

You need to assign the variable within the global environment (or whichever environment you want the variable to live in).

```
> a <- function(x) { assign(paste('train', x, sep = ''), 4, envir = .GlobalEnv) }
> ls()
[1] "a"
> a(1)
> ls()
[1] "a"      "train1"
```

Comment: Yes, this works (so +1), but most likely, @mobupu, it's the wrong way to do whatever it is you're trying to do. Generally, `assign` should be avoided, and even more so, from within a function to the global environment. There's both more R-native ways to do things like this, and, this way leads to hard-to-read-code which leads to bugs.

Comment: What's a more R-native way? Admittedly I don't use `assign` in my own work. I agree that it's hard to read.

Comment: Hard to say exactly without knowing what the use case is, but likely, something with a list. Even just `myvars <- list(); a <- function(mylist, name, number) {mylist[[name]] <- number; mylist}` would be a possibility.

Comment: Thank you for all the answer. I now see that it was indeed a bad idea to go that way.

Comment: In fact I want to do a feature selection and the idea is to generate different subsets of features with a function,generate a train set for each subset, then use the output of this function in another function (let's say lm() ) to test each subsets.                                                               
 the number of subsets is variable and I don't know how to store them in order to re-use them later.

Comment: @mobupu In this case, create a list of subsets like what Aaron suggested and use functions like `lapply` (which applies a function to each element of a list and returns a list) to run `lm` on each subset. This will give you a list of `lm` objects which you can then do further analysis.